# Does ID always increase when adding new objects to GAE Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm building an client/server-app where I want to sync data. I'm thinking about including the largest key from the local client database in the query so the server can fetch all entities added after that entity (with **key** > largest_local_key).

1. Can I be sure that the Google App Engine always increase the ID of new entities?
2. Is that a good way to implement synchronization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, IDs do not increase monotonically.

Consider synchronizing based on a create/update timestamp.

Comment: Isn't it risky to synchronize based on timestamps? When data is added on the client, they might not have synched times? And sometimes new objects are longer back in the past because it was added on a client a long time ago and then recently synched?

Comment: Only the server would generate or care about timestamps. The client would check for updates using a query cursor.